# ng-pattern to allow spaces between words

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

I am looking for a `regular expression` that prevents **special characters and only allows letters, numbers, dash (-), underscore (_) an space**.

This regex works great but it doesn't allow for spaces between words.

For example, if enter `"123  456"`, i get custom error i defined. 
How i can tweak this reg to allow space between words as well in addition to letters, numbers, dash and underscore.

```
<input type="text" name="serialNumber" data-ng-model="SerialNumber" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*$/" maxlength="100"/>
<div data-ng-if="Form.serialNumber.$error.pattern" class="error">Please enter valid serial number</div>
```

Comment: did you want to allow spaces or hypen or underscore at the start or at the end?

Comment: DO you want to allow empty value?

Comment: @ Avinash Raj and @vks yes i would like to allow only hypen or underscore at the start and not space.

Comment: @Avinash Raj Only alphanumeric, _, - and space between words.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to allow a space in your input, you need to include it into the character class.

According to [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btext%5D):

> **ngTrim
>   (optional)** 
>   If set to `false` Angular will not automatically trim the input. This parameter is ignored for `input[type=password]` controls, which will never trim the input.
>   
> *(default: true)*

So, if your input field is not password field I'd recommend:

```
ng-pattern="/^[\w -]*$/"
```

The `\w` stands for `[A-Za-z0-9_]` in JS, the underscore does not have to be escaped and the hyphen at the end of the character class does not need escaping either.

Answer (score 8):

I think I found a very simple and basic solution for my requirement `i.e. to allow alphanumeric, _, - and space. Space should be allowed between word and not leading and trailing space.`

```
ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9\_\- ]*$/"
```

Anybody find issue with it , let me know please.

Comment: Your regex allows leading or tailing spaces. Either split that into 3 groups, where the middle one allows spaces or rework your regex completely. See here: https://regex101.com/r/sB8vL2/1

Comment: See version 2 of your regex splitted into 3 groups, with only middle one having spaces here: https://regex101.com/r/sB8vL2/2

Comment: @ Asunez - ng-trim default is true which will remove leading or trailing spaces.

Comment: My bad, wasn't aware of that. Thanks for clearing this up!

Answer (score 0):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+(?:\s+[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)*$
```

Construct your regex this way to capture `words` and not `spaces` at start or end.

Comment: won't match an empty value

Comment: @vks ng-trim default is true so that will do the needful for leading / traliing spaces. correct me if i am wrong here.

Comment: @immirza in that case you can simply use `^[a-zA-Z0-9\s_-]+$`

Comment: @ArunPJohny Isn't that what `ng-required` is for?

Comment: @RGraham yes.. so if I want to allow blank.. and if content is there then validate of the pattern

Answer (score 0):

You may try the below lookaround based regex.

```
^(?!\s)(?=$|.*[a-zA-Z0-9_-]$)[a-zA-Z0-9_\s-]*$
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this pattern to solve the issue

```
ng-pattern="/^(\D)+$/"
```

Answer (score 0):

pls     ng-pattern="/^[\w -]*$/"

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it